# how to detect dotnet 2 or newer is installed in machine

Tags: inno-setup

how to change this code to detect DOTNET v2.0

```
   dotnetRedistURL = 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/a/c/aac39226-8825-44ce-90e3-bf8203e74006/dotnetfx.exe';

  // Check for required netfx installation
  if (not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v1.1')) then begin
    dotNetNeeded := true;
    if (not IsAdminLoggedOn()) then begin
      MsgBox('MyApp needs the Microsoft .NET Framework to be installed by an Administrator', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      Result := false;
    end else begin
      memoDependenciesNeeded := memoDependenciesNeeded + '      .NET Framework' #13;
      dotnetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{src}\dotnetfx.exe');
      if not FileExists(dotnetRedistPath) then begin
        dotnetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotnetfx.exe');
        if not FileExists(dotnetRedistPath) then begin
          isxdl_AddFile(dotnetRedistURL, dotnetRedistPath);
          downloadNeeded := true;
        end;
      end;
      SetIniString('install', 'dotnetRedist', dotnetRedistPath, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dep.ini'));
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom try out these links

- [.NET Framework 1.1/2.0/3.5 Installer for InnoSetup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetfx_innosetup_instal.aspx?msg=2865844)
- [InnoSetup - Detecting and Downloading .NET 2.0](http://www.systemwidgets.com/Blog/tabid/61/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/55/InnoSetup--Detecting-and-Downloading-NET-20.aspx)